# How auto-collapse sidebar for window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

When the screen size is reduced, the hamburger menu appears and the side menu closes automatically. The problem is that the sidebar is not closing and only the hamburger menu is appearing.

To automatically collapse the sidebar according to the screen size i use Bootstrap 5, built-in responsive utility classes. First, wrap my sidebar content in a div with the class "collapse" and an ID that i will use to toggle it. Next add a button or icon that will trigger the toggle action, with the "data-bs-toggle" attribute set to "collapse" and the "data-bs-target" attribute set to the ID of the collapse div. But this doesn't work im my case.

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

navbar-brand
{
    font-size: 2em;   
}

.sidebar {
    width: 12.5em;

}

.main {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    color: #0d6efd;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
}


.header {
    background-color: #4481fc;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
    padding: 0rem 0.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width">

    <!-- http://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/ -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" rel="stylesheet">
    <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"></script>
    <link href="/static/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Sidebar colappse is the problem</title>
</head>

<body> 
    <div class="d-flex flex-column bg-success">
        <div class="bg-info w-100 h-15 " >
            <nav id="navBrand" class="bg-light navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark navbar-expand-md navbar-light " >
                <div class="headerNav container-fluid bg-success">
                    <div>
                        <button aria-controls="sidebar" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-target="#sidebar" data-bs-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand align-text-lg-start" href="/"> <span class="blue">DESPESA$ PESSOAI$</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="" width="64" height="64" class="rounded-circle me-2">
                            <strong>mdo</strong>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1" style="">
                            <li><a class="nav-link dropdown-item" href="#">Perfil</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link dropdown-item" href="#">Configurações</a></li>                    
                            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link dropdown-item" href="/logout"><img class="iconImg" src="/static/img/logout.png"/> Sair</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </nav>    
        </div>
        <div id="navbarDisplay" class="navbarDisplay"   ></div>
        <div class="w-100 h-80">
            <div class="d-flex h-100  ">
                    <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar collapse-horizontal align-items-start  h-100 p-2 text-white bg-light"  >
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="/dashboard"><img class="iconImg" src="/static/img/home.png"/>  Dashboard</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="/lancamentos"><img class="iconImg" src="/static/img/information.png"/>  Lançamentos</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link " href="/categoriaList"><img class="iconImg" src="/static/img/categorizacao.png"/>  Categoria</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link " href="/despesasList"><img class="iconImg" src="/static/img/money.png"/>  Despesas</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link " href="/receitasList"><img class="iconImg" src="/static/img/wallet.png"/>  Receitas</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class=" flex-grow-1 w-75 bg-secondary">
                        <main class="container-fluid py-1 text-center">

                        </main>
                    </div>
                </div>                
             </div>
          <div>
          <div style="footer w-100  h-5">
             <footer  class=" mb-3 small text-center h-5">© 2023 Honey TI. Todos os direitos reservados - Desenvolvido por Alex Ribeiro de Faria</footer>                  
          </div>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

S